# std::swap not working with std::array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have some code that requires me to put some data into a `std::array`. I thought I could do this by swapping two arrays and discarding one of them. Here's the code

```
int main()
{
    std::array<double, 10> a;
    std::array<double, 5> b;
    /*populate b*/
    /*swap them round*/
    std::swap(a, b);
}
```

But I get a very strange compiler error (MSVC2013).

```
CashFlows.cpp(27): error C2665: 'std::swap' : none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types
include\exception(502): could be 'void std::swap(std::exception_ptr &,std::exception_ptr &)'
include\tuple(572): or 'void std::swap(std::tuple<> &,std::tuple<> &)'
include\thread(232): or 'void std::swap(std::thread &,std::thread &) throw()'
while trying to match the argument list '(std::array<_Ty,_Size>, std::array<_Ty,_Size>)'
with
[
  _Ty=double,
  _Size=0x0a
]
and
[
  _Ty=double,
  _Size=0x05
]
```

which I don't understand. What does `std::tuple<>` etc. have anything to do with this?

Comment: What a Procrustean error...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you seriously going to keep that name? This is a nice clearly set out question. Thank you!

Comment: @KerrekSB: With some discretion, I reach for my dictionary...

Comment: @Bathsheba Kerrek probably refers to: [_"It's all about the size"_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procrustes).

Comment: @Bathsheba _"Are you seriously going to keep that name?"_ Wait until they'll change their avatar :-P ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The objects `a` and `b` are *fundamentally* different *types* as they are different template instantiations.

Therefore you can't use them together in `std::swap` as the arguments must be the same type.

Your compiler can't find an appropriate overload (granted, the ones it shows you do seem odd), so issues the error that you see.

Comment: so the arrays need to be the same size?

Comment: Yup. Or consider using a different type. Do you have a good reason to pick `std::array` over `std::vector`? Do you need to use `std::swap`? I don't really grasp how you can replace a `std::array<, 10>` with a `std::array<. 5>`.

Comment: This answer neglects to mention `swap_ranges`. The only issue is that a dual range version doesn't exist yet, making it bad to use on arrays of different lengths. Otherwise you could just do `std::swap_ranges(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());`.

Comment: How would swapping a 10-element array with a 5-element array make sense?  What's going to happen with the 6th through 10th elements?  Remember that a is a fixed-size 10 element array, and thus must still be a 10-element array when it's done.  (Same with b as a 5-element array)

Answer (score 1):

> which I don't understand. What does `std::tuple<>` etc. have anything to do with this?

You just sort out reading error messages a bit further upon hints. The compiler just lists the available constructor declarations that could be possibly appropriate:

> **could be**
>
> ```
> void std::swap(std::exception_ptr &,std::exception_ptr &)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> void std::swap(std::tuple<> &,std::tuple<> &)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> void std::swap(std::thread &,std::thread &) throw()
> ```

You can see these also [documented here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).